# problem with jquery versions

Tags: jquery

Currently  I'm using  Jquery 1.3 in  my website but some of the features like custom scrollbar is not working in 1.3 .but it working in 1.4 ..
I'm didn't dare to switch my plugin 1.3 to 1.4..if I did so  it effects the all remaining functionality in my website ..can i get that feature of 1.4 plugin features .without changing that 1.3 plugin.???

thanks.

Comment: Voted to close, vague and not enough information.

Comment: @alex which information you need ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to update your code to work with the latest version of jQuery. When you run into specific problems with the update post them here on SO and we can help you, but be specific, post your code and describe the problem/solution you want accurately.

Comment: Okay.I'll do it .
Thanks @themerlinproject